# How do I iterate and save an array using cy.each in Cypress with Cucumber Preprocessor?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to get all the parameters in my upcoming course card div. It has course information, course data, course name, teacher's name and enroll button. I tried the following code and it prints 1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4. Instead of repetition how can I just have 1 2 3 4?

```
Then('validate upcoming coursecard all parameters',()=>{
    var a = []
    cy.get('.upcoming_course_card')
    .each(($li, index, $lis) => {
        a.push($li[0].innerText)
        console.log(a)
      }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly:

1. Assuming you want to output exactly the element that is pushed into the array in each iteration, then use the index to achieve that like:

```js
Then('validate upcoming coursecard all parameters',()=>{
    let a = []
    cy.get('.upcoming_course_card')
    .each(($li, index, $lis) => {
        a.push($li[0].innerText)
        console.log(a[index])
      }) 
})
```

2. Assuming you just want to have a summary log statement at the end that prints out all the contents of your array, then you just need to place the log statement outside the loop:

```js
Then('validate upcoming coursecard all parameters', () => {
  let a = [];
  cy.get('.upcoming_course_card').each(($li, index, $lis) => {
    a.push($li[0].innerText);
  });
  console.log(a);
});
```

And as a tip, think about using **let** instead of **var**. You can find details about this in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) for example.